# arithmetic progression with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

hello I have this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1982, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990], 'VB': [13215.8, 13215.8, 13215.8, 13215.8, 13215.8, 13215.8, 13215.8, 13215.8], 'coef': [0, 0.0814, 0.1213, 0.1380, 0.1601, 0.1906, 0.2355, 0.3080]})
```

```
   year       VB    coef
0  1982  13215.8  0.0000
1  1984  13215.8  0.0814
2  1985  13215.8  0.1213
3  1986  13215.8  0.1380
4  1987  13215.8  0.1601
5  1988  13215.8  0.1906
6  1989  13215.8  0.2355
7  1990  13215.8  0.3080
```

I want to add a column `'result' = VB - (previous` result`) * coef`

first value of result is `VB = 13215.8`

- **for example for second row**

```
VB - (previous `result`) * coef

13215.8 - 13215.8 * 0.0814 = 12140.03
```

- **for third row**

```
13215.8 - 12140.03 * 0.1213 = 11743.21
```

And so on ...

Comment: Are all `VB` values the same?

Comment: yes but they could change

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your goal iterating over the rows like this:

```
result = df['VB'][0]
results = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    result = row['VB'] - result * row['coef']
    results.append(result)
df['results'] = results
print(df)

    year       VB    coef       results
0  1982  13215.8  0.0000  13215.800000
1  1984  13215.8  0.0814  12140.033880
2  1985  13215.8  0.1213  11743.213890
3  1986  13215.8  0.1380  11595.236483
4  1987  13215.8  0.1601  11359.402639
5  1988  13215.8  0.1906  11050.697857
6  1989  13215.8  0.2355  10613.360655
7  1990  13215.8  0.3080   9946.884918
```

Comment: this is only a sample data, i have millions of lines, i did it but it took a lot of time

Comment: @Náthali I don’t think there is a way to vectorize your operation since each value needs to know the previous value.

Answer (score -1):

You can look up the docs to see how to add a new column to a dataframe
For your example, you can do it this way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1982, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990], 'VB': [13215.8, 13215.8, 13215.8, 13215.8, 13215.8, 13215.8, 13215.8, 13215.8], 'coef': [0, 0.0814, 0.1213, 0.1380, 0.1601, 0.1906, 0.2355, 0.3080]})
new_col = [df['VB'][0]]
for i in range(1,df.shape[0]):
    new_col.append(round(df['VB'][i] - new_col[i-1]*df['coef'][i], 2))
df['new_col'] = new_col
print(df)

        VB    coef  year   new_col
0  13215.8  0.0000  1982  13215.80
1  13215.8  0.0814  1984  12140.03
2  13215.8  0.1213  1985  11743.21
3  13215.8  0.1380  1986  11595.24
4  13215.8  0.1601  1987  11359.40
5  13215.8  0.1906  1988  11050.70
6  13215.8  0.2355  1989  10613.36
7  13215.8  0.3080  1990   9946.89
```

Comment: this is only a sample data, i have millions of lines, i prefer to avoid loops